# custom bufferGeometry with texture

Tags: three.js

I did tests on particle systems some time ago. because I'm working on it again at the moment. i want to use a texture but i only get black particles. i think the problem lies in the uv coordinates but i don't know how to use it in this case.
I have described in the code where I suspect the problem.
how do i access the texture coordinates in the shader in this case

```
var camera, controls, scene, renderer, container;

var PI = Math.PI;
var clock = new THREE.Clock(); 

var plane;
var MAX_Planes = 2000;
var velocity = [];
var geometry;


function init() {

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, alpha: true} );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio ); 
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true; 
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
             
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    var aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight; 
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x000000 );
    
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight, 1, 100000 );
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 4000);

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.enableZoom = true;
    controls.enabled = true;
    controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
    
//---------------shader---------------  

    var VertexShader = `
        varying vec3 vUv;
        uniform vec3 pos;
        
        void main() {

        vUv = uv;

        vec4 finalPosition;

        finalPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( pos, 1.0 );
        finalPosition.xyz += vec3(position.x, position.y, 0.0);
        finalPosition = projectionMatrix * finalPosition;
        gl_Position = finalPosition;

    }`;

    var FragmentShader = `
        varying vec3 vUv;
        uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;
        void main() {

        gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(tDiffuse, vUv).rgb, 1.);
        //gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.8, 1.0); //just for testing
    }`;

  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var texture = loader.load( 'textures/test.jpg' ); //the texture is loaded correctly. I tested that with a box
                

    var uniform = { 
        tDiffuse: {value: texture}, 
        pos: { value: new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0) },
    } 

        var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {                  
        uniforms: uniform,                  
        vertexShader: VertexShader,
        fragmentShader: FragmentShader, 
        transparent: true,
        depthTest: false,   
        depthWrite: false
    }); 
    

//-------------------------------------------------
//create a plane: points, normals, uv
    const vertices = [
        { pos: [-20, -20,  0], norm: [ 0,  0,  1], uv: [0, 1], },
        { pos: [ 20, -20,  0], norm: [ 0,  0,  1], uv: [1, 1], },
        { pos: [-20,  20,  0], norm: [ 0,  0,  1], uv: [0, 0], },
        { pos: [ 20,  20,  0], norm: [ 0,  0,  1], uv: [1, 0], },
    ];

    const numVertices = vertices.length;
    const positionNumComponents = 3;
    const normalNumComponents = 3;
    const uvNumComponents = 2;
    //arrays for buffergeometry
    const positions = new Float32Array(numVertices * positionNumComponents * MAX_Planes);
    const normals = new Float32Array(numVertices * normalNumComponents * MAX_Planes);
    const uvs = new Float32Array(numVertices * uvNumComponents * MAX_Planes);
  
  //fill arrays with vertices
    var posPointer = 0;
    var nrmPointer = 0;
    var uvPointer = 0;
  
    for(var i = 0; i <= MAX_Planes; i++) {
        var posNdx = 0;
        var nrmNdx = 0;
        var uvNdx = 0;
            for (const vertex of vertices) {
                positions.set(vertex.pos, posNdx + posPointer);
                normals.set(vertex.norm, nrmNdx + nrmPointer);
                uvs.set(vertex.uv, uvNdx + uvPointer);
                posNdx += positionNumComponents;
                nrmNdx += normalNumComponents;
                uvNdx += uvNumComponents;
            }
        posPointer = i * posNdx;
        nrmPointer = i * nrmNdx;
        uvPointer = i * uvNdx;
    }

    //create buffergeometry and assign the attribut arrays
    geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, positionNumComponents));
    geometry.setAttribute('normal', new THREE.BufferAttribute(normals, normalNumComponents));
    geometry.setAttribute('uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute(uvs, uvNumComponents));

    var ndx = 0;
    var indices = [];
    //instead 6 vertices for the both triangles of a plane i used 4, so reindication is neccessary
    for(var i = 0; i < MAX_Planes; i++){
        indices.push(ndx, ndx + 1, ndx + 2, ndx + 2, ndx + 1, ndx + 3);
        ndx += 4;
    }
    geometry.setIndex(indices);


    var materials = [];
    geometry.clearGroups(); 

    for(var i = 0; i < MAX_Planes; i++){
        geometry.addGroup( 6*i, 6*(i+1), i );
        materials.push(material.clone());   
    }
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
    scene.add(plane); 


//----------------------velocity---------------------------
    
    for(var i = 0; i < MAX_Planes; i++){
        velocity[i] = new THREE.Vector3(
        Math.random()*2-1,
        Math.random()*2-1,
        Math.random()*2-1);
    }   
    
}//-------End init----------


function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );  
    render();
    
}//-------End animate----------

var loop = 0;
function render() {

    loop = loop + 0.5;

    for(var i = 0; i < MAX_Planes; i++){
    
    var pos = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        
        pos.x += velocity[i].x*loop;
        pos.y += velocity[i].y*loop;
        pos.z += velocity[i].z*loop;
        
        plane.material[i].uniforms.pos.value = pos;

    }
    plane.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
    plane.geometry.attributes.uv.needsUpdate = true;

    camera.updateMatrixWorld();
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); 
    renderer.render(scene, camera); 
    
}//-------End render----------
```

my initial assumption was wrong. I suspect the problem now in the regrouping. with the following line i see the texture

```
plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

but that's no use to me. each group "one plane inside the bufferarray" should have its own material and for that i need the grouping but obviously i'm doing something wrong because i don't see anything with the "materials" array

Answer (score 0):

ah, the problem is that the texture is not cloned when the material is cloned. cloning the material only works if I work purely with shader code without texture. if i want to have the texture i have to instantiate the material every time in the for loop